# Sort NSArray containing åäö

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Need help to sort NSArray that contains åäö (Swedish chars)
I am using for the moment

```
[keyArray addObjectsFromArray:[[names allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

But this is sort A Å Ä Ö

Comment: try using `localizedCompare:` for comparison selector.

Comment: What's the problem with the sort order?  It looks fine to me as a non-Swedish-speaker.

Comment: @Richard Wikipedia says the order is A-Z, Å, Ä, Ö

Answer (score 5):

This question is similar to the one I answered here [Sort NSArray of NSStrings like Addressbook on iphone sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845446/sort-nsarray-of-nsstrings-like-addressbook-on-iphone-sort/6845892#6845892) . You need to do a diacritic insensitive search.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aar", @"åäö", @"aao", nil];

NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [(NSString*)obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}];
```

*Note: `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` requires iOS 4.0 and above. For iOS < 4.0 use `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`.*

Answer (score 0):

As the comments below the question and the answer states; `[NSString localizedCompare:]` is the best way to get words with åäö sorted the right way.

As I understand it `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` treats å and ä as a and ö as o and that is not what you want when sorting swedish.